# appropriate usage of proceeded

Tags: word-usage

*The investigator proceeded at the crime scene?*

Is this correct? Can I use the word *went* instead?

Comment: This doesn't sound right. Do you mean *proceeded to(wards) the crime scene*?

Comment: You can't *proceed at* something. It would be *proceeded to*, which sounds strange in this case. I think Cerberus is right, that it would be *towards*.

Comment: @Alex: I disagree. There nothing wrong with [proceeded to the scene](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22proceeded+to+the+scene%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and I don't see any reason why the fact of it being a ***crime** scene* should make any difference. Google Books says that's 464,000 results, against only 1680 for BrE ***towards*** and 552 for AmE ***toward***. OP's only problem is it should be ***to***, not ***at***. Cerberus just means *toward/s* is a credible possibility, not a favoured alternative over *to*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I never said there was anything grammatically wrong with it. I just don't think it's as clear as *towards*. Especially, because towards conveys direction and *proceeded to* makes me do a double-take (wondering if I missed a verb).

Comment: @Alex W: And I never said there's anything "wrong" with *toward/s* - just pointing out that *to* is favoured in Google Books by a factor of over 200:1. So you should have said *"Cerberus is right, that it would be **to**"* - or repeat his (careful) bracketing of the "possible" extra letters.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Carry on, boys. I like how I'm being analysed. My intuition first threw up *towards*, then *to* second. So I'd prefer *towards*, for some reason I cannot explain, but *to* also sounds fine. Perhaps the reason is indeed Alex's subconscious expectation of an infinitive after *proceeded to*. That would make sense; but then why in this context specifically, but not in other contexts? One thing that might be relevant is that *proceed to* + object is the only choice for abstract things, like *the next stage* or *the second point on the agenda*.

Comment: @Cerberus: We don't know the *exact* context - but in general, if you *go/proceed **to** X*, you ***will at some point arrive*** there. Partly because those particular verbs usually imply arrival, but mainly because ***to*** pretty much *always* implies getting there, with verbs of movement. To ***move*** doesn't strongly imply one way or the other, so the meaning hinges almost entirely on the preposition. If you *move **to** X* you'll almost certainly get there; if you *move **toward/s** X* you'll definitely end up nearer to X after moving, but probably not actually arrive there.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is incorrect. @Alex is correct that [*at*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/at) is not a preposition which is *usually* paired with proceed.

While *at* does indicate a place (or a time), it tends to be a stationary place:
*at* one's address, one's house, one's favorite restaurant, at high altitudes. One looks *at* a photo, sits *at* a table, relaxes *at* the movies, is puzzled *at* the crime scene.

[*To*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/to)/*toward(s)* express motion, as does proceed. One goes *to* a home, one turns *towards* a sound, or *to* can be used for expressing contact (she applied lacquer *to* her nails).

*to* implying motion can also be expressed as [*towards*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/toward?s=t): (O.E. toweard "in the direction of") toward a point, person, place, or thing, implied or understood.

> The third German machine gun fired on Pfc. Dutko... wounding him a second time as he proceeded *toward* the enemy weapon...

Having said all that, you can substitute **went** and be correct.

---

In the dark, and in a bitterly cold drizzle, which made the handling of metal objects more hazardous, he **proceeded to** remove the bombs, dismantling each in turn.